# Databricks: How to switch from R Dataframe to Pandas Dataframe (R to python in the same notebook)

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe, databricks

I am writing R code in a Databricks notebook that performs several operations in R. Once the dataframe is cleaned up, I would like to invoke it in a python cell using '%python' and therefore use python code to continue operations on the dataframe.

I would thus like to transform, within the python block, my R Dataframe into a Pandas dataframe. Does anybody know how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: It might be worthwhile checking out the [reticulate](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/) R package, as it is facilitating R/Python interoperability. Don't know if it's the way to go with databricks though - they might have another solution for that.

Comment: you should convert it into a Spark DataFrame then back into Pandas, although you should be able to solely rely on PySpark, what are you trying to do ?

Answer (score 11):

I think the namespace between different kernels is separate on Databricks. So even in the same notebook, you will not see an R variable in Python or vice versa.

My understanding is that there are two methods to share data between kernels: 1) using the filesystem (csv, etc) and 2) temporary Databricks tables. I believe the latter is the more typical route[1].

1. Filesystem:

```
%r
write.csv(df, "/FileStore/tmp.csv")
```

```
%python
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("/FileStore/tmp.csv")
```

2. Temporary databricks table:

```
%r
library(SparkR)
sparkR.session()
df <- read.df("path/to/original_file.csv", source="csv")
registerTempTable(df, "tmp_df")
```

```
%python
df = spark.sql("select * from tmp_df").toPandas()
```

[1] https://forums.databricks.com/questions/16039/use-python-and-r-variable-in-the-same-notebook-amo.html

Answer (score 2):

Note: Since rpy2 release 3.3.0 explicit conversion is done as follows

```
import rpy2.robjects as ro

dt = pd.DataFrame()
```

**To R DataFrame**

```
r_dt = ro.conversion.py2rpy(dt)
```

**To pandas DataFrame**

```
pd_dt = ro.conversion.rpy2py(r_dt)
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work within the Databricks environment. The R object, within a python code chuck will not be found


NameError: name 'r_dt' is not defined

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem: No way to easily switch between R and Pandas dfs that's compatible with Databricks. r2py won't work, feather won't work, even tried converting an R df to a Spark df but the following Python cell still can't find it when I try running toPandas() on it. Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a straightforward way to do this; it takes a few steps in Databricks:

1. Convert R data.frame to SparkDataFrame
2. Register SparkDataFrame as a temp view (this can't be done on a regular data.frame or data.table)
3. Convert temp view to pandas or pyspark DataFrame

The second step is necessary for the Python cmd cell to be able to "find" the data frame. Otherwise you'll get the dreaded NameError mentioned previously.

Here's an example of what that might look like:

1. R cmd cell:

```html
df <- as.DataFrame(df)
createOrReplaceTempView(df, "df")
```

2. Python cmd cell:

```html
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# Create a SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Temp View").getOrCreate()

# Import the temp view
df_pandas = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM df")
```