# Calling a R function from a Python command/cel in Databricks

Tags: python, r, function, databricks

I am trying to execute an R function that needs an R-df and not a Pandas. Within databricks this is [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60658629/databricks-how-to-switch-from-r-dataframe-to-pandas-dataframe-r-to-python-in-t) Therefore I am looking if it is possible to call an R function from a command cell written in Python Databricks? (to write the pandas df and read it in R) An option could be creating a new notebook([Option1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65743432/calling-r-workbook-in-databricks),[Option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53898772/call-r-notebooks-on-databricks-from-second-r-notebook)).

However, if I simplify the problem to an only python problem, I obtain the following:

### Callee:

```
def checken():
  parameters=pd.read_csv("/dbfs/FileStore/tables/parameters.csv", header='infer') 
  test=parameters['test'][0]
  if test <0: 
    d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
    df.to_csv('/dbfs/FileStore/tables/test.csv')
  else: 
    d = {'col1': [2, 2], 'col2': [4, 4]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
    df.to_csv('/dbfs/FileStore/tables/test.csv')
  return
```

### Caller

```
d = {'test': [-2]}
parameters= pd.DataFrame(data=d)
parameters.to_csv('/dbfs/FileStore/tables/parameters.csv')
test=parameters['test'][0]
print(test)
dbutils.notebook.run("test", 1800)
result=pd.read_csv("/dbfs/FileStore/tables/test.csv", header='infer')    
print(result)
```

If I change 'test':-3, it will return the same df as shown before. In short, the function is not executed. Does someone sees the problem/solution?

Comment: why do you need python? why not read CSV using the Spark R interface?

Comment: The input variabels are created in Python. I am using an R Packages (qrnn) and like to perform a grid Search over the r function. Therefore, I like to call the cel multiple times.